# Set Chart-click property of Angular chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I would like to know that how I can set the chart-click property through java script for a given canvas element. I tried doing

```
  angular.element(document.getElementById(id))[0].attributes[attributeName].value =value;
```

but of no help I guess.
I think I am missing something related to binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native addEventListener Property to programmatically add a click property to the DOM element. It can be done like so :

```
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function(){
    //The function to be called on click
})
```

For more Info [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)